# Control Statement True or False

Tags: controls

Function returning `True` if in position 4 the word contain T Y or R and position 5 I, M, or Z, `False` if no match

```
def word():
   if ["T,Y,R"] in (word[3]):
      return True
   if ["R,Y,F,M"] in (word[4]):
      return True
      else:
   return False
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to test multiple variables against a value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112125/how-to-test-multiple-variables-against-a-value)

Comment: Please format your code better...